# Is any $K3$ surface of degree $8$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ the complete intersection of quadrics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here the base field is the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You may want to ask this on MO, where there are more algebraic geometers who might know the answer.

Comment: I can move the question there if you want (Please edit the question so that the body of the question contains the complete question, though)